# Pulsing marker plugin with the R leaflet package

Tags: r, plugins, leaflet

I want to add a pulsing marker to the map I built with the [R leaflet package](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/)
Here is [the plugin](https://github.com/mapshakers/leaflet-icon-pulse) I want to use. In order to do it, I wrote the following code from this [from this github account](https://gist.github.com/timelyportfolio/8f6c8cc27597466351ad377e6774c30f)

```
library(leaflet)
library(htmltools)
library(htmlwidgets)

# This tells htmlwidgets about our plugin name, version, and
# where to find the script. (There's also a stylesheet argument
# if the plugin comes with CSS files.)
esriPlugin <- htmlDependency("leaflet-icon-pulse",version = "1.0",
                             src = c(href = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mapshakers/leaflet-icon-pulse/master/src/"),
                             script = "L.Icon.Pulse.js",stylesheet ="L.Icon.Pulse.css")


# A function that takes a plugin htmlDependency object and adds
# it to the map. This ensures that however or whenever the map
# gets rendered, the plugin will be loaded into the browser.
registerPlugin <- function(map, plugin) {
  map$dependencies <- c(map$dependencies, list(plugin))
  map
}


leaflet() %>% setView(-52.520, 13.185, zoom = 5) %>%
  # Register ESRI plugin on this map instance
  registerPlugin(esriPlugin) %>%
  # Add your custom JS logic here. The `this` keyword
  # refers to the Leaflet (JS) map object.
  onRender("function(el,x) {
           var pulsingIcon = L.icon.pulse({iconSize:[20,20],color:'red'});
           var marker = L.marker([52.9167,13.9333],{icon: pulsingIcon}).addTo(this);
           }")
```

However, it does not work. I got a grey rectangle instead of a beautiful map with a beautiful pulsing marker. Anyone see something wrong in my code?

Comment: Change the first line of the final map call to `leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% setView(-52.520, 13.185, zoom = 5) %>%` and the `onRender` part to `onRender("function(el,x) {
           var pulsingIcon = L.icon.pulse({iconSize:[20,20],color:'red'});
           var marker = L.marker([13.185,-52.520],{icon: pulsingIcon}).addTo(this);
           }")` and you will see a map and a marker, though in my case it is not pulsating...

Comment: Yeah I can change the final map call. But I got the same onRender part that yours. Is there the good one? It seems you do not paste the corrected version of onRender.

Comment: The difference in the `onRender` I posted is `L.marker([13.185,-52.520]` where I've changes the coordinates so that the marker is in the center of the map extent specified with `setView`.

Comment: Hmm , ok, but  I still cannot see the marker. Thx for your help though.

Comment: The problem is that the CSS that makes the pulsing is not loaded. If you open the Viewer window from RStudio in Firefox (use the Show in new window button) and analyze the page with Developer tools (Inspector) you will notice this message The stylesheet https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mapshakers/leaflet-icon-pulse/master/src/L.Icon.Pulse.css was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/plain", is not "text/css". Try to load the css manually and everything works fine. Still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works with three remarks:

- the js and css file are stored locally
- the icon is displayed correctly in RStudio viewer but it does not pulsate
- With the "Show in new window" option in the Viewer everything works fine (tested in Firefox 48.0 and Chrome 53.0.2785.116 (64-bit))

This is the code (adjust the src parameter to match your file location):

```
library(leaflet)
    library(htmltools)
    library(htmlwidgets)

    # This tells htmlwidgets about our plugin name, version, and
    # where to find the script. (There's also a stylesheet argument
    # if the plugin comes with CSS files.)

    esriPlugin <- htmlDependency("leaflet-icon-pulse",version = "1.0",
                                 src = "/home/valter/Desktop/test",
                                 script = "L.Icon.Pulse.js",stylesheet ="L.Icon.Pulse.css")





    # A function that takes a plugin htmlDependency object and adds
    # it to the map. This ensures that however or whenever the map
    # gets rendered, the plugin will be loaded into the browser.
    registerPlugin <- function(map, plugin) {
            map$dependencies <- c(map$dependencies, list(plugin))
            map
    }


    leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% setView(-52.520, 13.185, zoom = 5) %>%
            # Register ESRI plugin on this map instance
            registerPlugin(esriPlugin) %>%
            # Add your custom JS logic here. The `this` keyword
            # refers to the Leaflet (JS) map object.
            onRender("function(el,x) { var pulsingIcon = L.icon.pulse({iconSize:[20,20],color:'red'}); 
                     var marker = L.marker([13.185,-52.520],{icon: pulsingIcon}).addTo(this); }")
```

Comment: @Valter Beaković, I'm sorry to ask you this but I'm a real noob at js. Can you explain me why this 2 arguments (el,x) function ?

Comment: The onRender function is from the htmlwidgets package. It requires three arguments: x, jsCode and data (data deafaults to NULL). x is passed with the pipe operator (%>%). Js code is the string containing the function. About the function arguments this is what the help file says:  The function will be invoked with three arguments: the first is the widget's main HTML element, and the second is the data to be rendered (the x parameter in createWidget). The third argument is the JavaScript equivalent of the R object passed into onRender as the data argument;

Comment: thks a lot for this comment @Valter Beaković